# $A\to B$ is integral extension and injection ring homomorphism. Given prime ideal $p\subset A$, $pB$ is proper.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This is a dumb question.

Given $A\to B$ is integral extension and injection ring homomorphism. Given prime ideal $p\subset A$, then $pB$ is proper.

Is there a way to see extension of $p$ in $B$ is proper without resorting to lying over thm or reproving lying over theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically no: the lying over theorem follows quickly from this fact, so any proof of this fact is essentially a proof of lying over.  Indeed, localizing at $p$, you may assume $A$ is local and $p$ is its maximal ideal.  If $pB$ is proper, then any maximal ideal containing it must lie over $p$.

But if you want a quick proof that does not directly go through lying over, here's one.  We may localize at $p$ and assume $A$ is local with maximal ideal $p$.  If $pB=B$, then there is a finitely generated $A$-subalgebra $B_0\subseteq B$ such that $pB_0=B_0$ (since only finitely many elements of $B$ are involved in writing $1$ as an element of $pB$).  Since $B_0$ is integral over $A$, it is finitely generated as an $A$-module.  But now by Nakayama, $pB_0=B_0$ implies $B_0=0$, which is a contradiction.